# Gravatar images are not fetched in Ultimate Member plugin

Tags: plugins

Is it not possible to use Gravatar images in Ultimate Member Plugin? Or is it an issue that its not working?

Under users tab (Ultimate Member -> Settings -> Users) "Use Gravatars" is enabled, still it shows empty/default gravatar than user's gravatar avatar/image.

Comment: Have you asked the plugin developer already? It's hard to tell without knowing the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my testing and [information from the developers](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/gravatar-not-showing-9/), Gravatars won't appear until you use the *Gravatar Transfer* feature to transfer the images to the local profile.

That feature can be enabled from *Ultimate Member* > *Settings* > *Extensions*.  Once it's activated, you can transfer the Gravatars from *Ultimate Member* > *Gravatar Transfer*.

You'll need to run that feature periodically in order to keep the Gravatars up to date.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was resolved by ticking the "Use Gravatar" box, leaving the "Gravatar built in image" as default in the dropdown. The next box labeled "Use Default plugin avatar as Gravatar's Default avatar" looks like it will override Gravatar images if you did not upload any custom images for your profile. I left it unchecked even though I did have custom images uploaded. My Gravatar is working everywhere on the site after this procedure.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the plugin (Ultimate Member) calls for Gravatar - which you can easily fix by following these simple steps:

1. Go to [gravatar.com](https://en.gravatar.com/)
2. Login with your wordpress.com credentials (don't worry if you don't
   have a wp.com account, if you use .org it works, too).
3. Edit the image, profile, etc.
4. Save changes and refresh your page to see, it's working now!